# Android Freeciv, how to load unit onto ships?

Tags: android, freeciv

Latest Android client as of time of writing.

I do not see an option for a Settler unit to be loaded onto a seafaring ship when they are BOTH in the same city, how can this be done?
I am stuck on one island.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to load ground units on a ship while the ship is on a city square. You need to move the ship a tile away, then you will be able to load the units on the ship.